# React Generating pdfs on components

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I want to be able to generate a pdf of the page. It needs to satisfy a few requirements

1. It must maintain the same styling (What is displayed on page must be what is displayed on pdf)
2. The pdf that is displayed/generated must be in letter size format (8.5in x 11in)

I've looked at a few libraries, but have not found one that meets these conditions

1. react-pdf - This allows you to state a paper size such as "A4" and it does meet condition 1. But it has limitations in that it forces you to use their basic components. You cannot put div and I imagine any other things generated by other libraries.
2. react-to-pdf - This will let me place my own components inside the pdf and it seems to let you choose paper size. However, it does not meet condition 1, and things may get cut off.

If anyone can chime in, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if point one can be perfectly achieved using any library as it is difficult to mimic the css styles applied to HTML components in pdf. However there this awsome library https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake which helps you to create pdfs in any style you want. What you probably can do is replicate the same layout of you page using pdfmake options

Comment: see this [link](https://printjs.crabbly.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 

@A.R.SEIF Print.js seems to allow us to print an existing pdf; however, I need something that can generate a pdf

Comment: @A.R.SEIF Oh, nevermind. I didn't scroll all the way down and I missed the "HTML Printing" part

Comment: add sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for debugging is better and explain problem.